# Error: html-webpack-plugin could not minify the generated output

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, webpack, html-webpack-plugin

while deploying to heroku i am getting following error . i am unable to resolve it as i dont know anything about html-webpack-plugin. help please.  my codes-https://github.com/utkarsh-cmd/Shop_INN

```
Creating an optimized production build...
    remote:        Failed to compile.
    remote:
    remote:        Error: html-webpack-plugin could not minify the generated output.
    remote:          In production mode the html minifcation is enabled by default.
    remote:          If you are not generating a valid html output please disable it manually.
    remote:          You can do so by adding the following setting to your HtmlWebpackPlugin config  :
    remote:          |
    remote:          |    minify: false
    remote:          |
```

Answer (score 6):

This may be happened because of a syntax error in index.html(inside public folder).
Eg: missing tag in index.html

Answer (score 2):

In my case error was:-

> Error: html-webpack-plugin could not minify the generated output.
> In production mode the html minifcation is enabled by default.
> If you are not generating a valid html output please disable it man  ually.
> You can do so by adding the following setting to your HtmlWebpackPl  ugin config:
> |
> |    minify: false
> |
> See https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin#options for det  ails.
> For parser dedicated bugs please create an issue here:
> https://danielruf.github.io/html-minifier-terser/
> Parse Error: <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable="no" />
>
> ...

As you can see on line 6 in `public/index.html`

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable="no" />  (I previously made change to it)
```

this was the actual  problem

So I replaced this with

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />(this is defualt one)
```

again `yarn run build.`
and problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

It can be a syntax error, like a missed quote or closing tag inside your file.html.

I recommend you to pass in your code into an HTML Validator or debugger, the automated check of errors for html can save you a lot of time.
I used this one and solved the tiny bug:
https://www.freeformatter.com/html-validator.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29860291)

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to edit your index.html and fix the errors ,I'll advise to use https://jsonformatter.org/html-validator to fix .html file